# changing data in table view on button clicked-iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am new for iPhone apps development.
In my app when i clicked on search button ,i want to display record in table view.
i m using array to change record in table view but its not working..please help

### viewController.m

```
-(IBAction) printButtonPressed : (id) sender
{
    mylabel.text =keyfileld.text;
    UITableView *tableView ;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    mylabel.text =keyfileld.text;

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",keyfileld.text];
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://demo.com/search_iphone.php?";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    [states removeObjectForKey:@"1"];   
    [states removeObjectForKey:@"2"]; 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if(serverOutput)
    {
        NSArray *listItems = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        mylabel.text = serverOutput;
        NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int x=1;
        for (int i=0;i<listItems.count; i++) 
        { 
            NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
            NSArray *listItemsid = [[listItems objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            NSLog(@"place name at index %d: %@\n", i, [listItemsid objectAtIndex:1]); 
            [states setObject:[listItemsid objectAtIndex:1] forKey:myString];
            x++;
            [stringArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:str,nil] atIndex:i];         
        } 

        datasource = [states allKeys];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];

        // [alertsuccess release];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    id aKey = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [states objectForKey:aKey];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;   

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why do you create tableView and cell in your printButtonPressed method?

Comment: because i want change table content on button pressed event.actually  want develop search functionlity in iphone apps which search records from my backend php application.i got correct php responce from server but it not displayed in table view structure..plesae help

Comment: ok, but why do you create a tableView that is not used in your code? you should have a tableView already, then you populate it with your content, don't you?

Comment: yes you are correct.please ignore that tableview ..now pleas tell how can chnage content of ex////

Comment: Please only mark an answer as an answer when an answer has been reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [tableView reloadData]; after loading the new data into the array's...

Comment: i have used [tableView reloadData]; but  still its not showing new data...please help

Comment: Have you updated the array with data before calling the reloadData?

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer when the comments imply that no answer has been reached?